# Finding Combination of Numbers that Sum closest to a target

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a combination of floats and I also have a few target values and I want to see if any combination of those floats (allowing duplicates) can sum as close as possible to the target values.

For right now I'm starting simple, and I want to see if I can use my current list of floats to reach just one target value. The sum can be off from the target by at most 0.5.

I've searched a lot of other codes, but usually they involved the combination of numbers reaching the target exactly, and did not provide leeway to be off by a certain amount.

It's very possible that no combination of the floats will reach the target value, and I want the code to reflect that.

EDIT: Example

Let's say I have to work with the combination [13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63]. If my target is 134 for example, the code should return [44.63, 44.63, 44.63] since that's the only combination whose sum is within 0.5 of 134. If the target was 28, I should get empty bracket [].

Comment: Hi Alan.  Please provide us with a [mcve] of your existing code, what it currently outputs, and then what you're expecting.   A sample dataset would be very beneficial as well.  You can add these details via an [edit] to your post.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/)? It's almost identical to what you are doing.

Comment: @gravity done. hopefully that helps

Comment: @blackbrandt I took a look and I'm not sure how to remove the weights from the code since the problem I have isn't constrained by weights.

Comment: I'm looking at your new post, working on an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to approach this is to iterate through all combinations of your numbers and keep track of which combination is the closest at the current time

```
import math
import itertools

numbers = [1,2,3,4]
target = 9
best_combination = ((None,))
best_result = math.inf
best_sum = 0

print("target:{}\nnumbers:{}".format(target,numbers))
# generate all combinations of the numbers
# including combinations with different lengths
for L in range(0, len(numbers)+1):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(numbers, L):
        sum = 0
        for number in combination:
            sum += number
        result = target - sum
        if abs(result) < abs(best_result):
            best_result = result
            best_combination = combination
            best_sum = sum
            print("\nnew best\n{}\nsum:{} off by:{}".format(best_combination, best_sum, best_result))

print("\nbest sum{} = {}".format(best_combination, best_sum))
```

Output

```
target:9
numbers:[1, 2, 3, 4]

new best
()
sum:0 off by:9

new best
(1,)
sum:1 off by:8

new best
(2,)
sum:2 off by:7

new best
(3,)
sum:3 off by:6

new best
(4,)
sum:4 off by:5

new best
(1, 4)
sum:5 off by:4

new best
(2, 4)
sum:6 off by:3

new best
(3, 4)
sum:7 off by:2

new best
(1, 3, 4)
sum:8 off by:1

new best
(2, 3, 4)
sum:9 off by:0

best sum(2, 3, 4) = 9
```

If the result at the end is too far off you can disqualify it at the end, or you can set the best result to what you want to be the cut off to be at the beginning.

So change `best_result = math.inf` to `best_result = 0.5` if you want the result to be closer than 0.5 to the given target.
The output of that (for input [1,2,3] and target 9) would be

```
target:9
numbers:[1, 2, 3]
best sum(None,) = 0.5
```

This is not the most efficient way to do this. There are ways to make short cuts, but this is the one of the easiest first approaches.

Edit, to allow duplicates I first generate a list with the maximum number of each number included so for your example it includes the maximum number of 13.02s and 16.08s and...

```
import math
import itertools

target = 134
numbers = [13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63]
n = len(numbers)
long_list_numbers = []
for number in numbers:
    long_list_numbers += ([number] * int(target / number))


best_combination = ((None,))
best_result = math.inf
best_sum = 0

print("target:{}\nnumbers:{}".format(target,numbers))

# generate all combinations of the numbers
# including combinations with different lengths
for L in range(0, len(long_list_numbers)+1):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(long_list_numbers, L):
        sum = 0
        for number in combination:
            sum += number
        result = target - sum
        if abs(result) < abs(best_result):
            best_result = result
            best_combination = combination
            best_sum = sum
            print("\nnew best\n{}\nsum:{} off by:{}".format(best_combination, best_sum, best_result))

print("\nbest sum{} = {}".format(best_combination, best_sum))
```

Output

```
target:134
numbers:[13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63]

new best
()
sum:0 off by:134

new best
(13.02,)
sum:13.02 off by:120.98

new best
(16.08,)
sum:16.08 off by:117.92

new best
(100.01,)
sum:100.01 off by:33.989999999999995

new best
(13.02, 100.01)
sum:113.03 off by:20.97

new best
(16.08, 100.01)
sum:116.09 off by:17.909999999999997

new best
(100.01, 44.63)
sum:144.64000000000001 off by:-10.640000000000015

new best
(13.02, 13.02, 100.01)
sum:126.05000000000001 off by:7.949999999999989

new best
(13.02, 16.08, 100.01)
sum:129.11 off by:4.889999999999986

new best
(16.08, 16.08, 100.01)
sum:132.17000000000002 off by:1.829999999999984

new best
(44.63, 44.63, 44.63)
sum:133.89000000000001 off by:0.10999999999998522

best sum(44.63, 44.63, 44.63) = 133.89000000000001
```

Comment: It seems somewhat like a [0-1 Knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/). You can use dynamic programming techniques to do a more time-efficient method.

Comment: Yeah, it is very similar to that problem, only difference being backpack weight must be < max here we want to be close to target, can be larger or smaller also there is no weighting on numbers. I might implement that into my solution for a little extra fun and efficiency.

Comment: [Here](https://www.guru99.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming.html) is a method of solving the knapsack problem using dynamic programming. You should be able to implement a solution where instead of using "if sum of floats is equal to target value" you would use "if sum of floats is within x amount of target value"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the code but it doesn't seem to allow duplicates. so far example your code wouldn't try the combination (1,1,1). What I'm unsure of is how to change the code so that duplicates are allowed.

Comment: @Alan What target did you use? I tried input 1,1,1 with target 3, 9 and it worked for me `best sum(1, 1, 1) = 3`
did you change best_result?

Comment: @Alan Just realized that I did not update my code after editing it to be more verbose while writing my answer. I don't think I changed the functionality but try it out now and let me know how it goes

Comment: @alexanderhurst so I updated my question with the sample list: [13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63] and target 134. Your code gives the best result:        new best
(13.02, 16.08, 100.01) when the correct answer should be (44.63, 44.63, 44.63)

Comment: Ohhh I completely misunderstood what you meant when you said that you want to be able to sum a single value from the input multiple times. That my friend is a much, much more difficult problem. The time complexity for that will also be much much higher... I will have to think about that one

Comment: @Alan I have updated my code to fit that, keep in mind that this addition makes a large time complexity enormous

Comment: @alexanderhurst Thank you for the new code. Yeah I was noticing problems with larger amounts of time when I had larger target values like 1500. I think I'm going to have to approach this problem a different way. Thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: Take a look at my new answer @Alan, I implemented a basic concept of dynamic programming to avoid redoing a lot of the work in an attempt to force the solution space to be smaller and skip redoing a lot of the work. It may still take too long for your needs however I don't know if there are many better ways to approach the problem other than a heuristic approach similar to making change with coins. That solution could find an acceptable solution but might not find a solution even if one exists and would not find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Took a break then went back to tackle this again. I have come up with a solution I believe to be much faster. Though it is still very very slow for large inputs and I have done no testing or calculations to support whether it is faster, I have not even tested it for correctness past two or three inputs. Posting it as a separate answer as it is a completely different method.

There is likely room to optimize specific functions in the program but the method is

initialization
start by adding each number to its own solution.
make an additional solution with no numbers and a sum = target + tolerance this servers as the initial score to beat
if any input number is better than this save it as the current best solution
add each number to a set of all sums achieved up to this point

iteration
keep track of what the current size of the sums set is, if this set grows we arent finished looking for solutions
make a temporary list for adding solutions, if we add directly to `self.solution_list` we add solutions to be checked in the current iteration, and we dont want this
now we loop through each previously found solution in our list and check what happens when we add each number in the number list to it
if the sum of the previously found solution and the current number is unique (not in sums set) and better than the previous solution we can add it to our temp list to update our solution list later and then update our set and best solution.
note that we also check if that solution is worse than the previous solution, the only way this happens is when we overshoot the target by further than the previous solution was close to the target, for example if the previous solution had a sum of 5 for a target of 6 and the current number to add is 3 adding three brings us to 8 which is a worse solution and no adding of positive numbers will make it better
now if the solution that we checked did not have any numbers that could be added to get closer to the target we dont have to check that solution anymore, its a dead end, so we can take it out of our solution list. We dont need to take it out of sums though or remove it from best sol if its there.
similarly if the solution we checked added every number then accessing this solution in the future makes no sense as adding values would result in values already in sums. therefore once again we can remove these
most solutions will be pruned out when all possibilities of adding numbers result in paths that have already been discovered
at the end we can check add the temp list to the permanent list and check if anything was added so sums to determine if we are finished. If the temp add list is empty the program should also be finished.

It might be a bit hard to understand, let me know if you have any problems but I hope this helps you out :)

```
class solution:

    def __init__(self, numbers, n_sum):
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.n_sum = n_sum

    def getNumbers(self):
        return self.numbers

    def getSum(self):
        return self.n_sum

class solutions:

    def __init__(self, numbers, target, tolerance):
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.target = target

        self.solution_list = [solution([num], num) for num in numbers]
        self.best_sol = solution([None], target + tolerance)

        for sol in self.solution_list:
            if abs(sol.n_sum - target) < abs(self.best_sol.n_sum - target):
                self.best_sol = sol

        self.sums = set(numbers)

    def iterate(self):
        sums_len = len(self.sums)
        add_sols = []
        for sol in self.solution_list:
            # if all get added to current sol then current sol will be obsolete
            # if none get added to current sol then current sol is a dead end
            # if either of these cases are true at the end we can remove this path
            # (leaving it as best solution if it is)
            added_all = True
            added_none = True
            for num in self.numbers:
                new_sum = sol.getSum() + num
                # if new sum is better that sol sum and not in all sums
                # it is a new solution
                if new_sum not in self.sums and abs(self.target - new_sum) < abs(self.target - sol.getSum()):
                    added_none = False
                    new_sol = solution(sol.getNumbers() + [num], new_sum)
                    # update the best solution if new sol is better
                    if abs(self.target - new_sum) < abs(self.target - self.best_sol.n_sum):
                        self.best_sol = new_sol
                    # update sums
                    self.sums.add(new_sum)
                    # add the new solution to a list to add at the end
                    add_sols.append(new_sol)
                else:
                    added_all = False
            # prune redundant branches
            if added_all or added_none:
                self.solution_list.remove(sol)
        # add the solutions
        self.solution_list += add_sols
        # return true when finished
        if len(self.sums) == sums_len:
            return False
        return True

target = 130
numbers = [13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63]
solutions = solutions(numbers, target, 0.1)

i = 0
while(solutions.iterate()):
    print(i)
    i+=1
print(solutions.best_sol.numbers)
```

Output for 0.1 tolerance and target 134

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
[None]
```

Output for 0.5 tolerance and target 134

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
[13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02]
```

for tolerance 0.5 and target 1340

```
0
1
2
.
.
.
134
[13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 44.63, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 44.63, 13.02, 13.02, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 44.63, 13.02, 13.02, 13.02, 100.01, 100.01, 44.63]
```

Comment: as a benefit this works with no imports :S. If anyone wants to review my code and point out any redundancies or improvements go ahead and Ill update my answer and give you props. Otherwise I'll leave it as is as long as it works and just provide clarifications.

Comment: One thing about this method/problem in general is if the input array includes a number that is much smaller than the target it has to do a lot of iterations to determine the best solution for example with `numbers = [13.02, 16.08, 100.01, 44.63, 0.1]` and target 134 this takes 1207+1 iterations and Some of those iterations are likely to span a very large solution space. with most sums to 1 decimal precision between 0.1 (- the solutions that have been pruned) all the way to 134.1 in being worked on in the iteration. Of course its hard to know how many because of the pruning.